# How do I mount a USB in plain XMonad?

Tags: usb, automount, xmonad

Now that I am using XMonad I find that my USB devices no longer automount when I plug them into my computer. How do I get them to automount again just like they did when I was using gnome?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The way that I have solved that problem is to use nautilus running the the background to continue to
manage that for me. You can do that like so:

```
nautilus --no-desktop -n &
```

If you happen to start XMonad using a custom .xsession file then that would be the perfect place to
put that line. Make sure you put it before the 'exec xmonad' command.

Answer (score 9):

I'd recommend one of the udisks-based solutions. uam seems to do the job without too much configuration. udisks-glue is also decent for scripting.

- [uam](https://github.com/mgorny/uam/):

> This is just simple tool for mounting pendrives and alikes when
>   inserted -- something like ivman or functionality integrated in
>   KDE/GNOME.

- [udiskie](https://bitbucket.org/byronclark/udiskie):

> udiskie is a simple daemon that uses udisks to automatically mount
>   removable storage devices.

Comment: Your option is a good one but I marked mine as the answer because it was simpler. (It was a one liner) Yours is probably better memory wise though, probably a little less top heavy. I still gave you an upvote.

Answer (score 2):

On Arch Linux [ldm](https://github.com/LemonBoy/ldm) works quite well with plain XMonad.

Disks will automatically mount to `/media`.  Disks may be unmounted with `sudo pumount` or `sudo umount`.

References:

- https://github.com/LemonBoy/ldm
- http://aur.archlinux.org/packages.php?ID=60088
- http://aur.archlinux.org/packages.php?ID=52272

Comment: I could not get the nautilus option mentioned on this page to work.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are better off with udisks. It comes installed by default (at least on Ubuntu) and handles the standard mounting and unmounting like a charm. You can read all about it here - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AutomaticallyMountPartitions

Btw as the documentation says, udisks is not gnome specific.